# Can I change permissions to my ruby on rails app based on which browser a user uses?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, browser, cross-browser

For example, say I only want the web app to be viewed on a tablet - would I be able to restrict access from desktop and smartphones so the following would happen:

-Desktop  and Smartphone user: Sees message that they would be better using a tablet i.e. it's the only way to view.  Doesn't have any user access- cannot login or sign up but can view content posted by tablet users.  if they want to interact, it restricts and tell them to sign up with a tablet.

Tablet user:  Is able to login, has full functionality of web app.

Is this possible in Ruby on Rails?

Comment: Yes it's possible - though generally a bad idea. This gem should help: https://github.com/neighborland/mobu

Answer (score 0):

It is generally bad UX/bad design to restrict based on browser type nowadays, but if you insist on doing so, you can get the user agent in `request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`.

This could be used in a `before_filter` to give you a `@user_agent` to work with like so:

```
before_filter :set_user_agent

def set_user_agent
  @user_agent = case request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
    when /Mobile/
      :mobile
    else
      :not_mobile
  end
end
```

And then branch based on @user_agent == :mobile.